# そうだ、投票しよう！

Tags: 討議, 投票の仕方

Stack Overflowでのあなたの一票は、信用度10点の価値があります。

リアルでの「投票」という言葉の意味から想像する以上に、Stack Overflowでは投票によってサイトのコンテンツや他の人の行動に直接的な影響を与えることができます。

- どういう質問を歓迎するかについて意志表示する
- どの回答が役立つかを評価する
- 信用度を生み出し、みんなの権限レベルがアップするのを助ける
- バッジももらえる

投票大事！積極的に投票しよう！

...ということで、一つ一つ見ていきましょう。

### 質問に投票する

質問にプラス・マイナス投票することで、どういう質問がよい質問で、どういう質問がよくない質問なのかの基準をみんなで形成していくことができます。質問した人へのフィードバックにもなりますし、後からサイトに入ってきた人へのガイドラインにもなります。

もちろん無闇に入れればいいというものではなく、自分なりの質問の評価にしたがって、それも他の人の票に惑わされることなく、票を入れるのが理想です。「これくらい点が入っていればもう十分だろう」と安心せず、質問を自分が読んだしるしを残していきましょう。

プラス投票する基準の例:

- よく書けているか?
- 他の人の役に立ちそうか?
- 自分も同じ問題を抱えていたことがあるか?
- 回答したくなるほど興味をそそる問題か?

マイナス投票する基準の例:

- 何を聞きたいか、はっきりしない
- ここで聞くには適切ではない内容である

投票による信用度の増減表:

```
+---+-------+------+
|   | 質問者 | 自分 |
| △ | +5    | 0    |
| ▽ | -2    | 0    |
+---+-------+------+
```

### 回答に投票する

Stack Overflowでは、得票数の多い回答ほど上に表示され、参考になる回答がすぐに分かるようになっています。質問する人・回答する人・投票する人がいて初めて、分かりやすく信頼できるQ&Aに育つのです。

回答の投票基準は質問よりシンプルです: 内容が正しく、より役に立つと思う回答にプラス票、間違っているような回答にはマイナス票を入れればOKです。

投票による信用度の増減表:

```
+---+-------+------+
|   | 回答者 | 自分 |
| △ | +10   |  0   |
| ▽ | -2    | -1   |
+---+-------+------+
```

### 投票は信用度を生み出し、サイトの経済を回す

Stack Overflowでは、コンテンツのクオリティを保つための管理機能がユーザーに開放されています。他の人の投稿を編集することから、クローズすること、さらには削除することもお互いにできてしまいます。

ただし、登録したばかりのユーザーに強力な力を持たせると危険なので、「信用度」というポイントをためることで徐々により強力な機能にアクセスできるようになる仕組みになっています。

「信用度」の獲得は、自分の投稿にプラス票をもらうことが主な手段になります。投票することが、相手がユーザーとしてレベルアップすることにつながるのです。

[image: 概念図]

みんなでレベルアップして、編集・クローズ・タグの整備などの自治をどんどん出来るようになりましょう。それが、Stack Overflowを、クオリティの高い質問・回答が期待できる、自分が使い続けたくなるようなQ&Aサイトに育てることにつながります。

### 投票でもらえるバッジ

投票を奨励することのあかしとして、バッジがいくつか用意されています:

- (銅) [「投票日」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/suffrage) 1日に30回投票した
- (銅) [「総選挙」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi) 1日に投票できる上限である40票を使いきった
- (銀) [「市民の義務」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) 300回以上投票した
- (銀) [「スポーツマンシップ」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/sportsmanship) 自分が回答した質問への他の人の回答に100回プラス投票した
- (金) [「鑑識眼」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) 600個以上の質問に投票し、かつ投票の25%以上が質問への投票である

投票された側として獲得できるバッジは[さらに沢山あります](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)（抜き書きするのをあきらめたほどです）。

バッジの獲得が主目的になってしまうと、実際の評価に沿わない投票をしてしまいそうで危険な面もありますが、ひとつの裏目標として楽しみにするのもよいと思います。

### 参考資料

他のStack Exchangeサイトでも、「投票しよう！」というメタ投稿は多数あります。

- [公式ブログ記事: Vote Early, Vote Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/) - これが引用されていることが多い

  - [和訳ドラフト](http://translatedby.com/you/vote-early-vote-often/into-ja/)
- [tex.SEのメタ投稿](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/vote-early-and-often) - これも他のサイトで引用されている
- [codereview.SEのメタ投稿](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/612/2134) - この投稿を書くにあたって参考にしました

["vote early"で検索](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=site:meta.*.stackexchange.com+"vote+early")すると他にもたくさんヒットします。

Answer (score 3):

今更ながら、個人的な見解を。 ento さんの言っている、「経済を回す」の側面を、ちょっと違った視点で眺めてみたいと思っています。

スタックオーバーフローは、大きく分けて「質問者」「回答者」「モデレーション実行者」の役割があると思っています。もちろん、コミュニティメンバーは、これらの役割のうち同時に複数を行いうるし、すべての役割として参加する方が、コミュニティから得られる恩恵も大きくなるとは思いますが、あくまで役割として分割するとこうなると思っています。

この役割で見たときに、それぞれの役割は、互いに下記のような影響を及ぼすと考えます。

- 「質問者」は、「回答者」がいい回答を書いてくれればくれるほど、質問をしたくなる
- 「回答者」は、「質問者」がいい質問を書いてくれればくれるほど、回答をしたくなる
- 「モデレーション実行者」は、「質問者」と「回答者」に対して投票などによって P/N フィードバックを行う。良い質問は vote up されるし、よくない質問は vote down や close されていく。

[image: スタックオーバーフロー参加者の相互作用]

この図にある通り、「質問者」ないし「回答者」として参加するのが主たる目的だとしても、モデレーション行為を行うことで、自分がより参加しやすくなるような影響をコミュニティに対して行える考えます。そのモデレーション行為の中でもっとも基本的かつ重要なのが、投票であると考えています。

投票は、「質問」や「回答」を直接投稿しなくても、コミュニティとしてどっちの方向にこれからの「質問」やこれからの「回答」が進んでいくかに影響を与えます。なので、自分にとってのより価値のある方向にコミュニティが進んでいくのを促進させるためにも、投票を積極的に行いましょう。