# 投稿修正の最小が６文字なので、１語のtypo(誤変換)が直せない

Tags: 討議

投稿された内容に誤変換を見つけたので修正しようとしたのですが、６文字以内の修正リクエストとなってしまい修正できません。

スペースをいれるという手はありますが、何か他に回避策みたいなのはあるのでしょうか？
それとも、１語のtypoは修正せずに目をつぶろう？

Comment: どの投稿のとこが誤変換なのでしょうか？

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/4995/php%E3%81%A7exit%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%BF%85%E8%A6%81%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B
のはなまるアンサー回答で、去勢的 -> 強制的　を直そうとしました

Comment: モデレータ権限だと修正出来ました。一語の修正が出来ないケースの対応はコミニュティ管理者に確認してみます。

Comment: 英語が前提のlimiter設定なんでしょうかねぇ…（関連話題ですが"変更履歴には10文字以上書け"といわれるのがたまに困ります）

Answer (score 7):

最小６文字のコンセプトは「推奨編集」とつながります。

編集を推奨するとき、[レビュー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review)に入り、もう一人のユーザーがその編集を承認しないといけません。そのため、一文字の編集でも、二人の時間を使ってしまい、コミュニティの負担が上がります。

信用度が[1,000以上](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)になると承認が不要になるので、一文字でも編集することができます。

当サイトが成長しながら投票が増え（[そうだ、投票しよう！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1528/%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86%e3%81%a0-%e6%8a%95%e7%a5%a8%e3%81%97%e3%82%88%e3%81%86?cb=1)）、信用度の高いユーザーも増えます。その間は一文字を直すと同時に他のミス（変換ミス、書式ミス等）を直せばいいと思います。

もちろん、日本語だからこそ、６文字が多すぎる可能性もあります。英語版では文字数に関わる制限が多く、日本語に不適切な設定もあると思います。６文字を１文字はしませんが、３文字等が適切と思ったら、[機能の要求](/questions/tagged/%e6%a9%9f%e8%83%bd%e3%81%ae%e8%a6%81%e6%b1%82)として投稿してください。

Answer (score 0):

## 回避策

試しに別アカウントを作って以下のように自分の回答を修正してみました。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/6075/revisions
文章末尾に、

> #文字数制限対策（このコメントは削除してね＞＜

という文言を入れ、文字数制限を回避している点がポイントです。（今回はこれ無しでも文字数足りてましたが。）

**追記: @unarist さんのコメントのとおり、この文言より参考元回答の`&nbsp;`の方が適当と思われます。**

あとはレビュアーの方で、「編集内容を改善」ボタンから上記文言を削除し承認してもらえば、前述のページにある履歴のようになります。
編集履歴は多少汚れますが、回答者への信用度も付与されます。この文言がレビューで気付かれなかった場合に備え、絵文字やAAで装飾しても良いかもしれません。

## 蛇足

こんな事で回避できる時点でそもそも編集の重要性についての判定基準がおかしいですねｗ
本家でも[同様の質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)があり、様々な問題点が指摘されています。日本語・英語関係ない話といえるでしょう。今回の私の方法も[同質問への回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90014)を参考にしたものです。
こういったものを見ていると、文字数によってその重要性を判定するのは乱暴だと言えると思います。
（また個人的には、[この編集合戦](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4673436/revisions)を見て強くそう思いました。信用度1000以上同士の戦いですし、ニッチなケースですが。）

対案としては、1文字の編集でも可能とし、しかしレビュアーによって悪い編集とみなされればその分信用度が減っていくようなスタイルが良いかもしれません。
私は今後、前述の回避策使うので機能要求に対する興味はないですが。

（運営の方へ： 前述のアカウントは既に削除しましたが、本アカウント「lowcac」には承認時に信用度+5が付与されました。これを信用度についての不正な操作とみなしアカウントを削除していただいても構いません。）

Comment: レビューで取り除かなくても見た目に影響しないという点で、元回答にあるように `&nbsp;` を使った方がいいのでは・・・？

Comment: @unarist それだとレビュアーに意図が伝わりにくく、「なんでこんなもの入れてるんだ」と無意味な混乱を招くかと思ったんですが、消し忘れられたり履歴を汚すデメリットの方が大きいですかね？

Comment: @lowcalc 編集サマリで補足してもいいですが、結局気にする人は編集して削除するだけかなと。個人的にはこのためだけにレビューで削除させる編集提案は承認するかどうか悩みそうです。

Comment: @unarist なるほど、修正しました。ありがとうございます！