# 回答の承認をしない、または承認という機能を知らないユーザーが多い？

Tags: 討議

以下のように、"承認"という機能がありますが

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer
- [回答を承認するとどうなりますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%82%92%E6%89%BF%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)

おそらく"承認"という機能を知らないのか、適切そうな回答が付いてるにも関わらず、承認がされないままの質問を一定数見かけます。
場合によっては、明らかに解決して、質問者もコメント欄でお礼を言ってるにも関わらず、承認されてないものもあります。

"承認"という状態になっていれば、ひと目で解決したことや、それ以上特に別の回答が必要ないことがわかり、回答者にとって「まだ別の回答すべき質問なのか？」がわかりやすいので、出来る限り承認の機能は使っていくべきだと個人的には思っているのですが、気にしすぎでしょうか？

さすがに、わざわざ一つ一つの回答に自分の回答だろうが他人の回答だろうが
「この回答で解決したなら承認してください」
と書き込むのも面倒で気が引けるし、"承認"という機能をどのくらい使うべきか、どの程度重要なのか？などを含めて、みなさんの意見を聞きたいです。

また、もし「承認を使うべき」という場合、承認機能を知らない人(?)にどうやって広めればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 24, accepted):

今まで英語版でも[何回も討議をしていました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=accepted+answer)。例：[Questions without accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171305/questions-without-accepted-answer)

結論は基本的に：

1. 承認された回答より、プラス票の多い回答の方が信用度高いです
2. サイトに質問を投稿し、離れてしまう人が多いので、承認された確率を１００％にできません

承認されているかしていないかを悩むより、[いい回答をプラス票にどんどん投票しましょう](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1528/%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86%e3%81%a0-%e6%8a%95%e7%a5%a8%e3%81%97%e3%82%88%e3%81%86?rq=1)！

### プラス票の多い回答の方が信用度高い

質問者が回答を承認すると「この回答は役に立ちました」と言う意味があります。当コミュニティはプラス票を与えると、意味は「当サイトのエキスパートがこの回答はいいと思っています」。

そのため、承認された回答は重要ですが、**プラス票の方が重要です**。

英語版の「トップ回答」を見ると、承認されていないが、ベストな回答がわかりやすい回答が多いです：

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property

もうちょっと見ると、承認された回答より、プラス票の多い回答があります。基本的に、承認された回答が「どうやって」を説明するだけですが、プラス票された回答は「なぜ」も説明します。両方は大事ですが、自分で何かを検索すると、承認された回答より、プラス票の多い回答を読みます。

### 承認された確率を１００％にできません

どうしても、すぐサイトから離れる質問者がいます。例えば登録していないユーザーが次回尋ねたらクッキーがないと承認できないとか、回答を自分で探したのでサイトに来ないことがあります。

システム上では、承認するようにヒントを与えます。例えば、質問者が回答にプラス票を投票すれば、赤で下記のメッセージが出ます：

> チェック マークをクリックして、これを承認された回答としてマークすることができます。

そして、承認されなくても大丈夫なように、メインページの「未回答」が承認されているかしていないかではなく、スコア１点以上ある回答があれば、「回答済み」としてサイトが見ています。

> [image: 未回答]

もし自分の回答が承認されていない場合、もちろんコメントで質問者へ[案内できます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)が、質問者がサイトから離れた可能性が高いため、それで解決ならない場合が多いです（弊職が一回未承認質問一覧に[コメントを入れました](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222761/google-chart-tooltips/14270917#comment20949928_14222761)が、一年以上かかった回答もありました）。

Comment: なるほど、やはり英語版でも既に色々と知見はあったのですね。色々と参考になります、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 9):

私見ではありますが、承認は必要だと思います。
質問のクローズがなされたのかどうなのか明確になります。

また、承認した後は、質問者は他の回答を求めているのか、継続的にこの質問を見ないという意思の表れにもなりますし、回答者や閲覧してる人も解決方法はどうなったのか、が明らかにできます。

メタで挙がっていました「マルチポストに関する質問」にもありますが、きちんとクローズできていることが肝心なのでは…と。

Answer (score 9):

承認機能がよくわからない、という人の参考になればと思い「[回答を承認するとどうなりますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1735/8000)」を作成しました。個人的な感想ですが、ヘルプセンターは文章で短くまとめられているものの、わかりやすいか、読もうと思えるかというと微妙なところです。

#### 承認の必要性

承認機能でなければならない理由としては、一覧で見たときに見分けがつく、回答者への信用度加算、というぐらいでしょうか。

- [Community♦](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1418/8000) に発掘されないように→プラス投票すればよい
- 複数の回答のうち、どれが質問者の役に立ったのか→コメントでも構わないでしょう
- 「まだ別の回答すべき質問なのか？」→同上

信用度の変化は回答者のモチベーションにもつながる可能性がありますし、チェックマークをクリックするだけで済むのですから、やってくれるといいなあと思います。私はコメントで促すことが多いです。

それより承認もコメントもしないというのが気になりますが、これこそどうしようもないので・・・。

#### どうやって知ってもらうか

SOを初めて使う人はどうやってそんな機能を知るのでしょうか。ツアーではこう書かれています。

> 質問者は、1つの回答に「承認済み」のマークを付けることができます。
>   承認された回答が完璧な回答であるとは限りません。あくまでも基準は質問者の役に立ったかどうかです。

サイトの紹介としては問題ないと思いますが、ここに「回答がもらえたらぜひ承認してください」といったニュアンスはあまり感じられません。

ヘルプセンターには「[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)」という記事があります。ただここにたどり着くには、

1. ヘルプセンターを開き
2. 「質問にあたって」の「[さらに表示](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)」をクリックし
3. 下から二番目に並んでいる「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?」

という手順を踏む必要があります。これは何かを疑問に思わないとたどり着けないでしょう。

なので、質問者向けのチュートリアルを用意した方がいいのだろうかと考えることがあります。

- 質問にはこんなことを書いてほしいです・マークアップできますよ
- 質問は編集できますよ
- 回答をもらったらプラス投票＆承認してくださいね・締切は不要ですよ

ちょっと親切すぎる気もしますが・・・。

Answer (score 1):

トップバーの「最近の実績」の横に、「承認していない質問の件数」を表示してはどうでしょうか？そこをクリックされたら、まだ承認していない質問の一覧を表示します。こうしておけば、最初に質問をしたユーザーでも、回答が付けば承認するべきなのだと、気づきやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 1):

何故「承認」なんだろう? と思うことがあります。
回答者が欲しかった回答であって、「承認」は違うだろう、と。
この単語のせいで意味/ニュアンスが通じなくなってるのかもしれません。
といってろくな代案はありませんが、
「これだ! 機能」「回答選択機能」
あたりいかがでしょうか。

Comment: 確かに「承認」というのは、今ひとつ合ってない気がしますね。「解決」とか「解決済」というのが合っているような気がします。やはり、中々使ってもらえない、気づいてもらえないというのは、それなりの原因があると思われます。改善を求む！

Comment: @9walk 以前このサイトの用語を議論した際には「ベストアンサー」という表現が挙がっていたようです（http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/265/8000）。呼び方を変えるのはいい案だと思うのですが、この質問は「承認してくれないケースをどう考えたらいいのか」といった話で解決してしまっているので、具体的な提案は新たに質問として投稿していただけるとより意見が得られるかと思います。

Comment: そうですね。解決済みであることに気付かず新たな回答を投稿してしまいました。すみません。

Comment: @masm 今回は別質問にしたほうが目立っていいかなと思っただけで、解決済みの質問に新たな情報や別解を回答すること自体は問題ないと思います。念のため。

Comment: 理解しました。たぶん。というわけで、別質問にしてみました。ご意見ありがとうございました。

Comment: その別質問へのリンクです: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1852/%E6%89%BF%E8%AA%8D-%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B