# 質問者に承認を促すスニペットはありませんか？

Tags: 討議

[回答の承認をしない、または承認という機能を知らないユーザーが多い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1784/2376) に関して、

- 質問者がSOにアクティブである(プロフィールから最終ログイン時間が確認できるはず)
- (第三者視点で)質問に適切と思われる回答が既にある
- それでも質問者からの一切の反応(投票、承認、コメント等)がない
- それらの状態でしばらく放置されている

のような条件を満たしている場合、それは**回答者**をはじめ**様々な利用者**をモヤモヤさせるのではないかと思います。(立て逃げ……と呼んでいいのでしょうか。)

誰にも投票されずに放置されれば後にCommunityに掘り返されることもありますし、(気付いた人が投票すればいいのかもしれませんが)専門外の質問だと迂闊に投票できなかったり質問者の評価が必要になるでしょう。

それ以上の補足が無ければ新たな回答は不要と判断されますよね(そう判断する人は投票すればいいのですが……)

上記のよう放置された質問は**他のユーザー**にも気障りになることが考えられます。

このような場合にコメントで承認や投票、問題点の指摘を促したい処ですが、これに定型文があると多くの人がそれを指摘(?)しやすいのではないかと思います。

如何ですか？

(具体的な数値等はひとまず指定していません。)