# より良いサイト利用を促すコメントのスニペット(定型文)を集めませんか？

Tags: サポート, コメント

より良いサイト利用を促すコメントの頻出文例を、定型文/スニペット/テンプレートとして集めませんか？

この質問の経緯として、スタック・オーバーフローに不慣れな方の質問に対して、[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)で投稿の改善を提案することがあります。
提案コメントを繰り返していると、以前のコメントと同じヘルプやメタ質問へ誘導したいケースが出てきます。
例えば、[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)や[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)、[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)などです。

こういったコメントを作成する都度、ヘルプやメタ質問を検索し、リンク先URLをマークアップに編集し、似通った言い回しを記述していると、多少の時間がかかったり誤字やリンク先の誤りが発生したりします。
よくあるコメントを一か所に集めて再利用することで、早くて安定して上手いコメントができるのではないでしょうか。

もちろん投稿に適したコメントを1つ1つ心を込めて手入力するのがベストですが、コピペであっても素早く的確に改善を促すことがBe niceな時もあると信じています。

もしご賛同いただけましたら、回答欄に再利用しやすい形でコメントの定型文/スニペット/テンプレートを貼り付けていただけますと幸いです。
(個人的にはURLのマークダウンが１か所にまとまっているだけでも十分助かります)

**関連する質問**

[質問者に承認を促すスニペットはありませんか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1791)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

この回答はコミュニティwikiです。
お気軽に加筆修正してください。

### 良い質問

#### マークダウン例

```
[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)
[スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)
```

#### 文例

```
ソースの一部のみが切り取られているため、実行してエラーを再現できませんでした。[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考にして簡潔で実行可能なコードの追記してください。
```

```
具体的にどこで困っているのかをご質問から読み取れませんでした。
[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)を参考に質問を具体化して焦点を絞っていただくと、より良い回答をもらいやすくなります。
```

```
解決したい問題点が分かりにくく感じました。
[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)になっているかもしれません。
[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)を参考にして、質問で解決したいことをより明確にまとめてみてください。
```

```
ソースコードやエラーメッセージは、画像でなくテキストを貼り付けて質問してください。 
[スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)
```

### 回答の承認

#### マークダウン例

```
[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)
```

#### 文例

```
解決したようで良かったです。
ぜひ[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をお願いします。
```

```
[ありがとうコメントは不要](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)です。
解決したのであれば[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をお願いします。
```

### 自己回答を促す

#### マークダウン例

```
[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
```

#### 文例

##### 質問に直接解決方法が追記されている場合:

```
解決に至った情報は質問に直接追記してしまうのではなく、ぜひ **個別の回答** として投稿してみてください。当サイトでは [自己回答も歓迎しています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。 (質問はあくまで質問の体裁を保つべきです)
```

##### コメント欄のやり取りで解決している場合:

```
もし解決した場合には、コメント欄で終わらせずに **個別の回答** として投稿してもらうと、同じような問題で困った人の助けになります。当サイトでは [自己回答も歓迎しています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)。
```