# スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案

質問の文章にプログラムのソースコードやエラーログを書き写すのは面倒です。
プログラム開発画面をスクリーンショットして画像形式で貼り付けて質問しても良いでしょうか。

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Comment: よくある質問の案にするために質問と回答をコミュニティ wiki にしたいのですが、この操作は payaneco さんの側で可能でしょうか？　権限がなければ私の方で操作いたします。

Comment: 取り急ぎ回答をコミュニティwikiにしました。質問は変更できませんでしたのでご対応いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 質問もコミュニティ wiki にしました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

残念ながら良くありません。

質問文のソースコードやエラーログなどは**テキスト形式で**記述してください。
(テキストのコピーアンドペーストは、質問の労力として受容していただきたいです。慣れれば画像のアップロードよりも簡便になるはずです)

文章による説明が非常に困難で、画像を使用して説明すべきと判断した場合は問題ありませんが、画像だけで済ませるのではなくテキストによる説明も併記してください。

スクショを使うと良くない理由は下記が挙げられます。

- 画像のソースコードは回答者が再利用して追試することができない。

  - [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)もご参照ください。
- 画像内の文字列は検索結果にヒットしないため、Q&Aとしての価値が著しく下がる。

  - 似たような悩みを持つ第三者の役に立つためにも、画像ではなくテキストで書くことを推奨します。
- 画像のソースコードやエラーログは、右端や上下部分のテキストが見切れてしまうことが多い。

  - エラーログの隠れた場所に解決のヒントが隠されている場合があります。省略しないためにもテキストで書きましょう。
- 画像の方がテキストよりもデータ転送量が多い
- 環境によってはサムネイル画像が縮小されて文字を読みにくい
- スクリーンリーダーで読み上げることができない

エクセルに関連する質問の場合、質問で全く具体例を挙げないよりもエクセルシートのスクリーンショットを貼った方が明確な質問になります。
しかし中身のデータがCSVである場合や単純な配列変数で問題点の再現が可能な場合などは、テキストで記述することを優先してください。

なおソースコードやエラーログは[コードブロック](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)として記述してください。
行数の多いテキストをそのまま貼り付けると質問文全体のスクロール量が多くなりますが、コードブロックにすることで適切にスクロールパネル内にハイライト表示されます。

---

やむなく画像を貼る場合も、以下の点に注意してください。

- 画面のキャプチャであるなら、画像フォーマットは PNG (またはGIF) 形式を推奨します。
  jpeg 形式だと配色によっては文字がにじんで見えたり、リサイズ等でぼやけて見えづらくなる可能性があります。
- 画面全体をキャプチャするのは避け、説明に必要な範囲を予めリサイズ・トリミング (切り取り) してください。

  - 画像のどこに注目すべきかを明確にするため
  - 不必要な個人情報等を誤って載せてしまう問題を避けるため
- 文字が含まれる場合、きちんと文字が読めることを確認してください。