# 「承認」は言葉を変えてはどうか

Tags: 討議, 専門用語

[回答の承認をしない、または承認という機能を知らないユーザーが多い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1784/) において一旦は
議論されたことですが、私は何故「承認」なんだろうと思うことがあります。
質問者が欲しかった回答であって、「承認」は違うだろう、と。
この単語のせいで意味/ニュアンスが通じなくなっているのかもしれません。
この場で案を出して、いいものがあればそれに変更してはいかがでしょうか?

といって私にろくな案があるわけではありませんが、
「これだ!」「回答選択」
が思いつきました。

Comment: 参考までに、過去には「花まるアンサー」「ベストアンサー」という案が議論されています（うやむやになってしまったようですが）。 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/265

Answer (score 8):

私は「承認」ではなく「**解決済**」がよいと思います。
この「解決済」は質問者にとって、問題が解決したという意味です。
ベストアンサーという言葉は、多くの賛成票を集めた回答がふさわしいと思います。

#### 回答者にとって

回答者は役に立ちたいと思っています。そして、その評価は、承認されてポイントを貰うことで、なされています（票を獲得した時にもポイントを貰えますが...）。このようなシステムなので、回答者は未承認の質問を優先して回答する傾向があります。回答者にとって、**事実上「承認」は「解決しているかどうか」のメタファーです**。

#### 質問者にとって

「承認」という言葉だと、**何を承認するのかよく分かりません**。意味が分からないので**積極的には使われない**でしょう。「解決済」という言葉なら、他のQ&Aサイトでも一般的ですし、問題が解決した時にはマークする必要があることが伝わると思います。その結果利用率も上がるでしょう。

#### サイトを見る第３者にとって

スタックオーバーフローに初めて質問をしようとする人にとっては、自分の質問が受け入れられて、回答が返ってきそうかどうかが重要な視点となっていると思います。現状だと「承認」があまり使われていないので、**質問しても、あまり解決しないように見えます。**

#### プログラマ向けのQ&Aサイトしては競合がいる

スタックオーバーフローは素晴らしい仕組みをもっているのですが、質問数やユーザー数では劣勢です。現状では、質問も回答も良質かどうかは微妙です。反対票を受けることがあり敷居が高いせいか、質問が少なく、逆に変な質問が多いようにも感じています。

ある程度、**競合を意識して、ユーザー数や質問数を増やす努力をしないと、生き残れない**気がします。

※もっと運営側で迅速な判断、強力な運営があってもよいのでは？流れを作らないと。

Comment: 「解決済」は質問に使う言葉であって「採用」や「承認」を単純に置き換えられないように思うのですが、各所のテキストをどのようにすべきなのか具体例を挙げていただけないでしょうか？なお、承認機能が使われていない、もっとこの機能を使ってもらうことを考えるべきでは、というのは先日「[回答の承認をしない、または承認という機能を知らないユーザーが多い？](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1784/8000)」で議論されていた内容だと思います。

Comment: 各所のテキストをすべて洗い出して発言したものではありません。ただ、自分が承認マークを付けるのは、質問が解決した時であり、解決してくれた回答に対してであるからです。その感覚と「承認」があまりにもかけ離れていたので、発言しました。そのように感じたユーザが１人いたということで、受け止めて下さい。

Comment: 私の後半が蛇足だったかもしれませんが、反論しているわけではないのです。「用語を変える」というのは最終的にはサイト上のテキストやヘルプの文章を変更することですよね。例えば「採用」に変えるなら、単純に文章中の「承認」を「採用」に置き換えればいいでしょう。ですが「解決済」に置き換えると文章がおかしくなるので、どのような文章を想像されているのだろう、と疑問に思ったのです。

Comment: 「解決済」は質問に使う言葉であって、というのは確かにそうなので、チェックマークを質問の横に移設するのはいかがでしょうか。この案も含めて、私が想像したヘルプの文章のほんの一部分はこんな感じです。
質問が「解決済」とはどういう意味ですか?
ユーザーが自分の質問に対してよい回答を受け取ると、そのユーザーに
は質問を「解決済」にするというオプションがあります。解決済は、
質問の隣の色付きのチェックマークで示されます。

Comment: 回答をマークする「承認」はやめて、質問をマークする「解決済」に、ということですね。その意見にはなるほどと思いましたが、システムの機能を現状から（そして他のSEネットワークのサイトから）大きく変えることになりますから、用語の変更と同列には扱えない議題のように思います。

Comment: +1　現状、問題が解決してもなかなか承認されない（必要なことだと認識されていない）ことは大きな問題だと思いますし（ステータスバーに未承認の質問数を表示するとか別のアプローチもありますが）、SOでは必ずしもベストアンサーを質問者自身が決める必要は無いということを伝える意味でも、「解決済」（あるいは「解決」）という表現は適切だと思います。
各所のテキストも「承認する」を「解決マークを付ける」などにするだけで利用者にも十分伝わると思うのですが、具体的にどのあたりで変換に問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: @バクダンくん 回答には「解決済」としか書かれていませんでしたが、「回答を解決済にする」では変ですよね。masmさんが書かれたように「質問を解決済にする」という解釈もあるでしょう。ですから、ちょうどあなたが書かれた「回答に解決マークを付ける」のように、具体例が欲しいと書いたのです。

Answer (score 1):

承認済印のマウスオーバーテキストは「質問者がこの回答を最も役に立つ回答として採用しました」となっています。既にどこかで、「採用」という語を使う判断または議論をしたのでしょうか？議論された結果なら、それでいいように思えます。

上記に限らず、名称そのもので使いみちを示せる名前が嬉しいです。使ってくれないユーザーは、おそらくサイトの使い方説明・ツアーなどを読んでいないので。

最初にベストアンサーという語を思い浮かべましたが、元記事のコメントにある

> 「ベストアンサー」について、「質問者が選んだ回答であって、一番よい答えではないかもしれない」というニュアンスをどうにか出せないかな、と思います。‌

を読んで、なるほどと。

Answer (score 1):

「解決済」では「承認」という言葉を単純に置き換えられないということで、[9walkさんの案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1861/8000)にはあーだこーだコメントしていましたが、結局は私も次のようなコメントを書くことが多くなりました。

> 解決に役立った回答をどれか一つ選んでいただき、左側のチェックマークをクリックして解決済みマークをつけていただけないでしょうか？

そこで、これと同様に「質問が解決したときにクリックするチェックマーク」ぐらいとして考えれば、機能の名前に触れずにUIやヘルプの文章を書くこともできるのではと。

> クリックすると質問を解決済みにします。この回答のおかげで問題が解決した、またはこの回答が最も解決の役に立った場合に選んでください。（もう一度クリックすることで取り消せます）

ただ、accepted answer をどう表現しようかと。例えば・・・

- 回答が承認されると、回答者には15点の信用度が与えられます
- 承認された回答は一番上に表示されます
- 承認した回答はいつでも変更することができます

解決マークがつけられた回答？解決策としてマークされた回答？質問者に選ばれた回答？

Comment: 議論自体は1年前のようですが、コメントしても良いのでしょうか。今でも承認という表現は新しいユーザにとってわかりにくいと感じています。本回答の文章を読んでいて思ったのですが、「 **役に立った** 」回答という表現であれば、回答に対してつけるのも文章を書くのも無理がなくなるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

[回答の承認をしない、または承認という機能を知らないユーザーが多い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1784/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AE%E6%89%BF%E8%AA%8D%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF%E6%89%BF%E8%AA%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD%E3%82%92%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%84) であった通りに承認が必ずしも必要なことではないのであれば、ベストとは限らないけれど質問者が認めた回答という意味で、ベストアンサーならぬ「**グッドアンサー**」など良いのではないかと思います。