# 新春の投票キャンペーン (2015年)

Tags: 討議, 投票, キャンペーン

今日は何回投票しましたか？

300回投票すると[市民の義務](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty)バッジがもらえますが、現在5人しか獲得していないレアなバッジです。みんなの信用度が上がるためには[投票が必要](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1528/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0-%E6%8A%95%E7%A5%A8%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86)です。

投票を増やすため、今週は「新春の投票キャンペーン」にします。投票するだけで豪華<sup>※</sup>な商品が当たります！

[image: 豪華な商品]

<sup>※ 実は豪華なものではなく、Tシャツです。スタック・オーバーフローのロゴが付いているので、それが豪華かな？いや、そうでもないなぁ。このロゴは[$512](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest/)がかかったコンテストで決まりました。豪華というより、素敵のほうがいいかな？</sup>

ルールは簡単です。今週投票を5回以上すると、抽選にエントリーできます。投票した数が応募券の枚数になります。

例えば：

> Aさんが5回投票
>   Bさんも5回投票
>   Cさんが10回投票
>   Dさんが20回投票
>
> 合計40ですので、AさんもBさんも40分の5の確率になります。Cさんは40分の10です。Dさんはなんと40分の20（半分）です。

来週の月曜日に結果を教えます。

さ、投票しましょう！

Comment: 1. メタでの投票は応募券になりますか? 2. コメントへのプラス票・回答の承認は対象外ですか?

Comment: メインサイトの投稿（質問・回答）への投票のみです。

Comment: 日本国外に住んでいる人と外国人は参加できますか?

Comment: @AndrewT. 海外に住んでもいいですが、届くまで時間がかかるだけです。

Comment: 抽選にエントリーするには何かエントリーフォームみたいなものに入力する必要があるのでしょうか？そうであればそのページはどこにありますか？それとも5回以上投票をしていると自動的に応募がされるのでしょうか？

Comment: @kojianu 自動になります。SQLのクエリーで５票以上の投票した方を引き出して、ランダムで一人を選びます。選んだ後、住所をメールで送りますが、事前に何もしなくてもいいです。自動と思っていいです。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

先月の週間平均投票数は368票でした。先週このキャンペーンで倍以上の740票になりました。

合計124人が投票し、ユーザー全体で信用度が6106点増えました。

そして、こちらのユーザーが抽選でTシャツを当てました：

[image: Seiei]

おめでとうございます！

参加ありがとうございます！今度もこのようなキャンペーンを実施する予定です。